# Реализация multipart POST запроса: передача картинки

Tags: captcha, post, java

Нужно реализовать `multipart` запрос, передать в нем картинку как это сделать?
хочу реализовать на java сервис antigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

См. примеры к [Http Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html). В частности ответ на ваш вопрос содержится в примере [Multipart encoded request entity](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/examples/org/apache/http/examples/entity/mime/ClientMultipartFormPost.java).